# How do I provide a region when deleting AWS IAM Access Analyzers with the Go SDK V2?

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-sdk-go, aws-iam-access-analyzer

I am trying to delete an IAM Access Analyzer using V2 of the Go SDK, but I keep getting the following issue:

> failed to call service: AccessAnalyzer, operation: DeleteAnalyzer, error: failed to resolve service endpoint, an AWS region is required, but was not found

I am not having issues using the SDK for resources under other services. My code is as follows, with the region set by env variables as per [this documentation](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/configuring-sdk/#specifying-the-aws-region):

```
        name := "myanalyzer"
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(),
        config.WithSharedConfigProfile(profile),
        config.WithRegion("eu-west-1"),
    )

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Error loading configuration", err)
    }
        resolver := accessanalyzer.NewDefaultEndpointResolver()

    client := accessanalyzer.NewFromConfig(cfg, func(o *accessanalyzer.Options) {
        o.Region = "eu-west-1"
        o.EndpointOptions = options
        o.EndpointResolver = resolver
    })

    input := &accessanalyzer.DeleteAnalyzerInput{
        AnalyzerName: &name,
    }
    
    result, err := client.DeleteAnalyzer(context.TODO(), input)
```

I have also tried to specify a resolver URL:

```
        name := "myanalyzer"
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(),
        config.WithSharedConfigProfile(profile),
        config.WithRegion("eu-west-1"),
    )

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Error loading configuration", err)
    }
        resolver := accessanalyzer.EndpointResolverFromURL("https://access-analyzer.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com")

    client := accessanalyzer.NewFromConfig(cfg, func(o *accessanalyzer.Options) {
        o.Region = "eu-west-1"
        o.EndpointOptions = options
        o.EndpointResolver = resolver
    })

    input := &accessanalyzer.DeleteAnalyzerInput{
        AnalyzerName: &name,
    }
    
    result, err := client.DeleteAnalyzer(context.TODO(), input)
```

This does not work either, returning an error of

> requestID: 85f3d4ca-dc1b-43a4-9272-a05adea0f9d7, error: api error InvalidSignatureException: Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not ''.

How can I provide the region so that the analyzer can be deleted? Any help would be much appreciated.

AWS SDK Go version: 1.5.0,
Go version: 1.16.3 linux/amd64